# Chicken breast cooked or still needs time?

Tags: chicken, pan

Is this chicken breast cooked or still needs time? I’ve seared it with a pan for 10 minutes and rested for 5 minutes already, please help[image]

Answer (score 4):

The only way to be sure is to measure the internal temperature of the meat. [FoodSafety.gov](https://www.foodsafety.gov/food-safety-charts/safe-minimum-internal-temperatures) says that chicken, including the breast, should be cooked to 165 F/74 C to meet food safety guidelines.

Searing for a given time and then resting is no indication of whether something is cooked, particularly for something with a widely variable size like chicken breast. The breast in your picture could be anywhere between about 4 oz (113 g) and 8 oz (226 g), and with such size differences,  different cooking times are needed to reach the required temperature.

We cannot tell from a picture whether this is cooked enough to meet this requirement. Get a meat thermometer to ensure that you have cooked your food properly.